# Fragment save instance state

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im using jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu on item click I load the fragment by setUpFragment(new Inbox())
in the Inbox  fragment I have a AsyncTask to load data for my listview everytime I navigate to a different fragment and then back to inbox Fragment the async task gets called.

```
 private void setUpFragment(Fragment fragment) {
     manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
         ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);

    ft.commit();

}
```

here is the Inbox Fragment class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(tag, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Retrieving the currently selected item number
    Log.e(tag, "onCreateView");
    // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    // Getting reference to the TextView of the Fragment
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

    // Setting currently selected river name in the TextView
    tv.setText("Calendar");

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.e(tag, "onStart");
    new Async().execute();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.e(tag, "onSaveInstance");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
Log.e(tag, "onPause");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e(tag, "onStop");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.e(tag, "onDestroyView");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(tag, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    Log.e(tag, "onDetach");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.e(tag, "Attach");
}

class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e(tag, "onPostExecute");
    }
}
```

code that calls setupFragment

```
private Fragment streamFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expert_main);
    setUpActionBar();
    initFragments();
    setUpFragment(streamFragment);

    setSlidingMenu();

}

private void initFragments() {
    streamFragment = new MyStreamFragment();
    calenderFragment = new MyCalendarFragment();

}


menu1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            menuPressed = 1;

            if(streamFragment == null)
                Log.e("stream fragment" , " null");

            setUpFragment(streamFragment);
            currentFragment = streamFragment;
            setTextViewBackground();
            menu_sliding.toggle();

        }
    });
```

Comment: where do you call asynctask?

Comment: I dont want the AsyncTask to be called everytime

Comment: onStart of Inbox fragment

Comment: You are creating a new instance of MyStreamFragment every time. Naturally, a new fragment is created, thereby calling the async task every single time. Instead, store the fragment in a private variable and use the same variable for calling setUpFragment - with the asynctask.execute in onCreate instead of onStart.

Comment: no change I have used replace in the setUpFragment would that be an issue

Comment: You still have not put "new Async().execute();" in onCreate() instead of onStart()... put it there and delete the one in onStart.

Answer (score 0):

Put "new Async().execute();" in onCreate() instead of onStart(). onCreate is called when the fragment is first created, while onStart is called every time the fragment resumes. Check the fragment [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).